# Issues with Dynamic Search Expressions in EF

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I currently am using a data structures similar to the following:

```
public class Individual
{
    //Other properties omitted for brevity sake

    public List<IndividualName> IndividualNames {get; set;}            
}
```

and

```
public class IndividualName
{
    public string FamilyName {get; set;}
    public string GivenName {get; set;}
    public string MiddleName {get; set;}
}
```

I am attempting to use some Dynamic search expressions to pass from my presentation layer to repository level (to actually apply the search).

However, I have run into some issues due to the fact that an Individual can have 1-M Individual Names, and I am trying to use LINQ to grab all of an Individual's IndividualNames so they can be queried.

For example's sake - this is what the expression currently looks like:

```
searchExpressions.Add(new SearchExpression("Individual
                                           .IndividualNames
                                           .Select(GivenName)
                                           .FirstOrDefault()"
             , ComparisonOperator.Contains, "Test");
```

This will currently only determine if the GivenName in the first IndividualName instance Contains "Test". The above works as it should - however I am a bit stuck in terms of how I would be able to determine if Any of the IndividualNames contained the string.

Any help would be appreciated - as I have tried several things without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would be looking for....

```
searchExpressions.Add(new SearchExpression("Individual
                                            .IndividualNames
                                            .Select(GivenName)",
                      ComparisonOperator.Contains, "Test");
```

You will also need to add a Contains Aggregate Method to the Dynamic Linq library. How to do this can be found here.
http://blog.walteralmeida.com/2010/05/advanced-linq-dynamic-linq-library-add-support-for-contains-extension-.html

Answer (score 0):

im not sure this is aplicable in your case, but maybe this lambda?

```
Individual.IndividualNames.Where(x => x.GivenName == "Test")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Menahem, but I still haven't been able to find a solution. The dynamic search expressions haven't been too kindly to using lambdas as of yet.

Comment: i ,see . well then how about using Contains() and implemeting IEquatable<T> ?